# Where to call setNeedsDisplay in order to update CALayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I have a view controller (`MagmaViewController`) which is managing a view called `MagmaView`. For the direct backing layer of `MagmaView` I have assigned my own customized CALayer subclass called `MagmaLayer` by putting the following into the implementation section of `MagmaView`:

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [MagmaLayer class];
}
```

I have some customized drawing that I want `MagmaLayer` to draw for `MagmaView`, so I put some drawing code into the `-(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef) context` method of `MagmaLayer`. The problem is that when I do this and run the simulator then MagmaView appears blank. I set a breakpoint in `MagmaLayer`'s `-(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef) context` method and it appears this method is not being called at all.

Obviously, I'm confused about the need and placement of the `setNeedsDisplay` command for triggering the drawing of this CALayer. First, I thought that, at least for the first initial appearance of a CALayer, that issuing a `setNeedsDisplay` command was not needed if the CALayer is a direct backing layer for a UIView, and that any UIView makes sure that its direct backing layer is properly drawn when needed and that only non-direct CALayer backing layers required special attention to make sure that they draw themselves. Is this not so? Also, where should I place the `setNeedsDisplay` command to make this direct backing layer `MagmaLayer` draw itself? Should the `setNeedsDisplay` command be in the initialization method of `MagmaView`, which is the view hosting the `MagmaLayer` here? Or should I go further up the chain and put the `setNeedsDisplay` command in `MagmaViewController`, the view controller which is managing `MagmaView` in, say, the controller's `viewWillAppear` method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your custom layer when to draw. The basic implementation will do not call `-(void) drawInContext:(CGContextRef) context` automatically. The basic setup is to set `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES` in the layers init method.
If you have custom properties which should trigger a redraw, you will have to implement / extend `+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key`.